# What happens in this code? (Executing a char buffer)

Tags: c++, c, function-pointers

Could somebody give me a complete explanation of what is happening in this second line of code?

I know that the address of the buffer containing the shellcode is casted to a function pointer which is executed. But I´m a little confused with all the braces and steps involved, so I need a little bit more detailed explanation.

```
unsigned char buf[] = "\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90";

((void(*)())buf)();
```

I tried to explain it to myself this way:

```
buf                     //address of the buffer containing code
void(*)()               //"type" function pointer returning void, no parameters
(void(*)()) buf         //cast buf to said type
( (void(*)()) buf )()   //take the outcome of the cast and execute it by appending ()
```

Is this correct?

**Edit:**
I am aware that DEP would block the execution and that even if it would execute, the program would crash because it would execute "random garbage" after the NOPs. My question is just about the syntax of the function call.

Comment: on a DEP-enabled system this will just crash

Comment: I am aware of that. Let´s just assume that DEP is not active and/or i have allocated executable memory using VirtualAlloc or something alike.

Comment: Apart from the last line, you're right. The last line just calls the `function()`.

Comment: On a non-DEP system it will probably crash as well. I am missing the `RET` at the end of the string. `\x90` is `NOP`. After the last `NOP` your program will unpredictably execute anything.

Comment: That is correct. I just put the NOPs in there instead of valid shellcode because i thought it could be considered spreading malware or something.

Comment: I agree with glglgl, the call will work but there's no return statement, i.e. IP won't be restored.

Comment: DEP stands for Data Execution Prevention.

Comment: It may crash (SIGBUS) because of wrong alignment on some platforms, RISC processors mostly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Cast `buf` (array name converted to a pointer) to a `void(*)()` function pointer

   ```
   (void(*)())buf
   ```
2. Call that function through the pointer

   ```
   (function_pointer)();
   ```

Notice that this is just wrong because of [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) rules

```
(void(*)()) buf() // Function call has a higher precedence over type cast
```

so another pair of parenthesis is necessary.

Eventually execute it (if [DEP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Execution_Prevention) permits it, this is system-dependent) and (if x86) *Nop-Nop-Nop,etc..*.

You're thus correct.

As a sidenote: the NOP code will crash your app as well: there's no return statement and [IP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_counter) won't be restored when that payload finishes.

Comment: Note: in C++03 and C99 casting a non-function pointer to a function pointer is not permitted (although it is a common extension). C++11 formally makes it optional.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this correct? I would like to have some more detailed/correct explanation.

Here's a cleaner alternative:

```
unsigned char buf[] = "\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90";

// ((void(*)())buf)();
// equivalent code:
typedef void (*void_callback)(); // declare the function pointer as a named type
void_callback callback = reinterpret_cast<void_callback>(buf);
callback();
```